# 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, xml, sales-order

I have created a module witch Generating order xml for ERP. I have created a Observer file but it gives me a Invalid method `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`.
My code is :-

```
protected function sendFile($filePath, $fileName)
{
    $_helper = Mage::helper('Piyush_orderexport');
    $_helper->log('Uploading the file to the FTP server...');
    if ($ftpResource = ftp_connect(self::FTP_HOST, self::FTP_PORT))
    {
        if (ftp_login($ftpResource, self::FTP_USER, self::FTP_PASSWORD))
        {
            if (ftp_put($ftpResource, $fileName, $filePath, FTP_ASCII))
            {
                $_helper->log("Upload of remote file '$fileName' complete (source file is '$filePath').");
            } else {
                $_helper->log("Warning: error cannot upload the file!");
            }
        } else
        {
            $_helper->log("Warning: error cannot login to the FTP server! Can't upload the file.");
        }
    } else
    {
        $_helper->log("Warning: error connection to the FTP server! Can't upload the file.");
    }
}

public function exportOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $event=null)
{
    $_helper = Mage::helper('Piyush_orderexport');

    $importStartDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $_helper->log('*** EXPORT ORDER START - ' . $importStartDateTime . ' ***');

    /* @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    //$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100000042');

    $orderIncrementId   = $order->getIncrementId();
    $orderTimestamp     = strtotime($order->getCreatedAt());
    $orderDate          = date("ymd", $orderTimestamp);
    $orderTime          = date("Hi", $orderTimestamp);
    $orderShipping      = number_format(round($order->getShippingInclTax(), 2),2);

    $_helper->log('Processing order '.$orderIncrementId);
    $_helper->log('Order state = '.$order->getState());
    $_helper->log('Order has been exported is '.$order->PiyushOrderExported());


   if ($order->PiyushOrderExported() != '1' && $order->getState() == $order::STATE_NEW) {

        $_helper->log('Exporting order '.$orderIncrementId);
        $_helper->log("\t- date = $orderDate");
        $_helper->log("\t- time = $orderTime");
        $_helper->log("\t- shipping = $orderShipping");

        $xmlFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir('base') .'/'. self::EXPORT_RELATIVE_PATH . self::EXPORT_FILE_NAME;
        $outputFileHandler = fopen($xmlFilePath,"w");

        $orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($orderItems as $item)
        {
            //$_helper->log("Item data: ".print_r($item->getData(),true));

            $itemSku                = $item->getSku();
            $itemQty                = number_format(round($item->getQtyOrdered(), 2),2);
            $itemRowTotal           = number_format(round($item->getRowTotal(), 2),2,'.','');
            $itemRowTotalInclTax    = number_format(round($item->getRowTotalInclTax(), 2),2,'.','');
            $itemTaxAmount          = number_format(round($item->getTaxAmount(), 2),2,'.','');
            $itemPlu                = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $itemSku)->PiyushPlu();

            $_helper->log("\t- processing order item $itemSku:");
            $_helper->log("\t\t- qty = $itemQty");
            $_helper->log("\t\t- row total = $itemRowTotal");
            $_helper->log("\t\t- tow total incl tax = $itemRowTotalInclTax");
            $_helper->log("\t\t- tax amount = $itemTaxAmount");
            $_helper->log("\t\t- PLU = $itemPlu");

            $xmlString="";
            /* create your xml here */

            fputs($outputFileHandler,$xmlString);
            //$_helper->log("xmlString = $xmlString");

        }

        fclose($outputFileHandler);

        $this->sendFile($xmlFilePath, self::EXPORT_FILE_NAME);

        $order->setPiyushOrderExported('1');
        $order->save();

        $importEndDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $_helper->log('*** EXPORT ORDER END - ' . $importEndDateTime . ' ***'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

}

I get following exception ;

```
2017-11-06T07:07:28+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order::PiyushOrderExported(Array
(
)
)' in D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\lib\Varien\Object.php:653
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\local\Piyush\OrderExport\Model\Observer.php(54): Varien_Object->__call('PiyushOrderExpo...', Array)
#1 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\local\Piyush\OrderExport\Model\Observer.php(54): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->PiyushOrderExported()
#2 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1338): Piyush_OrderExport_Model_Observer->exportOrder(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Piyush_OrderExport_Model_Observer), 'exportOrder', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#5 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#6 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php(2174): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#7 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(319): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_afterSave()
#8 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Transaction.php(151): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\Order\ShipmentController.php(120): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#10 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\Order\ShipmentController.php(220): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_ShipmentController->_saveShipment(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment))
#11 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_ShipmentController->saveAction()
#12 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#13 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 D:\Ashok\htdocs\new1\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

Comment: your issue is with this code `$order->PiyushOrderExported()`,  what is `PiyushOrderExported` here?

Comment: I don't know. a developer suggest me this code. Please help me to sort out this.thanks

Comment: searched find that It is the value from the piyush_order_exported column in sales_flat_order table

Comment: okay, then try `$order->getPiyushOrderExported()` instead of `$order->PiyushOrderExported()`

Comment: no good luck same error after edit.

Comment: how did you added that column in sales_flat_order table?

Comment: by custom module

Comment: <?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order'),'piyush_order_exported', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'nullable'  => true,
        'length'    => 10,
        'after'     => null, // column name to insert new column after
        'comment'   => 'Is order exported'
    ));

$installer->endSetup();

Comment: You have added it in wrong way, you should have created order attribute instead for directly adding column in the database table

Comment: how i create a order attribute in table

Comment: check this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936470/adding-a-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

finale i found the bug it is in Observer.php. I'm updating a wrong variable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/111420)

Comment: Hi Piyush ! i want a last  invoice id, how can i get it